# PrefixTree Insert method giving None

Tags: python

Creating a PrefixTree, no problem up till the insert function where I try to do it recursively.

```
class SimplePrefixTree:
    def __init__(self, weight_type: str) -> None:
        self.value = []
        self.weight = 0
        self.subtrees = []
        self.weight_type = weight_type

    def insert(self, value: Any, weight: float, prefix: List) -> None:
        new_tree = SimplePrefixTree(self.weight_type)
        if prefix == []:  # if prefix list is empty
            self.value = value
            self.weight = weight
        elif len(prefix) == 1:  # if prefix list has 1 item
            new_tree.value = prefix
            new_tree.weight = weight
            new_tree.subtrees.append(SimplePrefixTree(self.weight_type).insert(value, weight, []))
            self.subtrees.append(new_tree)
```

Now when I try to run this:

```
>>> a = SimplePrefixTree('sum')
>>> a.insert('a', 20, ['a'])
>>> a.subtrees
[<SimplePrefixTree object at 0x1171e9da0>]
>>> a.subtrees[0].subtrees
[None]
```

It makes no sense whatsoever because I created a class object and then called the method and the first time works, but the *elif* class object instance returns None. I have also tested to see if the *if* function works and the attributes are indeed mutated.

Comment: What are you trying to do in ``self.weight_type.insert(...)``. I guess there is a typo here. Maybe what you want to do is : ``new_tree.insert(value, weight, [])``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, it happened because the value stored in the subtrees variable is a SimplePrefixTree:

```
>>> a.subtrees
[<SimplePrefixTree object at 0x1171e9da0>]
```

therefore in the array it will store the location of the second SimplePrefixTree, if you would like to make it more appealing or display values you should add an **repr**() method to the SimplePrefixTree class.

as for this part:

```
>>> a.subtrees[0].subtrees
[None]
```

this is because there are no values stored in the subtrees variable of the second SimplePrefixTree.

Anyway, my point is, your code is doing exactly what it should, maybe you are just confused by the pointer values.

Sorry for the confusing explanation, hope it helps you understand what is going on.